# twitter widget that shows tweet on my homepage : twitter.com

Tags: javascript, twitter, web

I want to add a  twitter widget to my website that shows me recent tweets of the people I'm following. Exactly what I see when I goto twitter.com

I looked up the https://twitter.com/settings/widgets , but it only gives you widgets for your own tweets or some users tweets. ( not all the users that I'm following.)

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin : http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/
Allows you to display tweets from multiple users. Just add username of all the users you are following in the code.

```
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#fromtwo").tweet({
      avatar_size: 32,
      count: 4,
      username: ["seaofclouds", "laughingsquid"],//add usernames here
      loading_text: "searching twitter...",
      refresh_interval: 60
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are lot of ways you can customize twitter widget, choose list widget and create a list of people whose tweets you want to follow and then create a widget for that list

here is the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines